# Initialization not Working

Tags: c++, graph

I am using trying to solve the [Shortest Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) problem in `C++`. For that I have created the following `Graph()` constructor.

```
Graph::Graph(int NumberOfVertices){
    this->NumberOfVertices=NumberOfVertices;
    cout<<"Graph()"<<endl;

    //declaring the weight matrix
    WeightMatrix=new int*[NumberOfVertices];
    for(int a=0;a<NumberOfVertices;a++)
        WeightMatrix[a]=new int[NumberOfVertices];

   //initialising the weight matrix
    WeightMatrix[NumberOfVertices][NumberOfVertices]={0};

    ShortestPathArray=new int[NumberOfVertices];

}
```

I have two questions.

1. Why is a simple declaration like 
   `WeightMatrix=new int[NumberOfVertices][NumberOfVertices]` not allowed? I tried doing so but there were errors. I found the solution online, but am not able to understand it.
2. The initialization step is not working. The code doesn't proceed further than this statement `WeightMatrix[NumberOfVertices][NumberOfVertices]={0};`
   When I comment out this step everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1:**

The type of `WeightMatrix` is `int**`, so you cannot initialize it with `new int[...]`.

As you seem to have already fixed in your code, the right way is to initialize it with `new int*[...]`.

**Question #2:**

Initializing an array to a list of values is allowed only at declaration. For example:

```
int WeightMatrix[M][N] =
{
    {1,2,3,...},
    {4,5,6,...},
    ...
};
```

So you can fix the compilation error by changing this:

```
WeightMatrix[NumberOfVertices][NumberOfVertices]={0};
```

To this:

```
for (int i=0; i<NumberOfVertices; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<NumberOfVertices; j++)
        WeightMatrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is a simple declaration like `WeightMatrix=new int[NumberOfVertices][NumberOfVertices]` not allowed? I tried doing so but there were errors. I found the solution online, but am not able to understand it.

It should help to compare this to creation of an array on the stack, for which you can do:

```
int my_array[X][Y];
```

When you later say `my_array[x][y]`, the compiler's record of the value `Y` is used to find the `int` value at address `&my_array + x * Y + y`.  But, when you use `new` and specify a dimension at run-time, the compiler isn't obliged to store the dimension(s) involved - that would adversely affect run-time memory usage and performance.  Without such dimensions though, the compiler can't support a `[x][y]` notation, so it's misleading to let you use `new` as if it were creating a multi-dimensional array.  In practice, implementations sometimes store the single allowed array dimension in some extra memory they ask for when you use `new[]` so they can iterate over the right number of elements to call destructors, but they might want to avoid that for types such as `int` that require no destruction.

The expectation is that you'll work out the total number of elements you need:

```
int* weightMatrix = new int[NumberOfVertices * NumberOfVertices];
```

Then what's conceptually `weightMatrix[x][y]` can be stored at `weightMatrix[x * NumberOfVertices + y]` (or if you prefer `weightMatrix[x + NumberOfVertices * y]`).

I recommend writing a simple class that has an operator to provide a convenient notation ala `matrix(x, y)`:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    Matrix(size_t X, size_t Y = X) : X_(X), Y_(Y), p_(new T[X * Y]) { }
    ~Matrix() { delete[] p_; }

    T& operator()(size_t x, size_t y) { return p_[x * Y + y]; }
    const T& operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const { return p_[x * Y + y]; }

    size_t X_, Y_;
    T* p_;
};
```

Then you can write simpler, cleaner and more robust client code:

```
Matrix matrix(20, 10);

matrix(4, 2) = 13;
```

You can also easily put checks in `operator()` to catch out-of-bound indexing during development and testing.